# How to add a column to the Sub record inventory detail?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

How to add a column to the Sub record inventory detail?
just like expiration date on inventory number subrecord on Item Receipt, can we have a custom field for manufacturing date in inventory number subrecord. Is there any feature need to be enabled? Does NetSuite have any functionality of Production/Manufacturing date? or any way to create a custom field in inventory number subrecord that is visible in IR subrecord?

Answer (score 1):

In Netsuite go to
Customization -> Lists, Records, Fields -> Item Number Fields

If you have a production run you either have lot numbered or serialized inventory. You can make the field applicable to all Lot Numbered or all Serialized or to just specific skus.

Note that the items need to have been created as lot numbered or serialized items.  If the items you want to use were not created as such then you’ll need to replace them with new items. If you want to use the same skus for the new items you’ll need to rename the original items.

Comment: thank you for the answer
i am add a item number field but i didn't find from where i bring this field ,from where i am deployed the field to the Sub record